# Condición where fecha y hora

Tags: sql-server

Actualmente tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQnet_Locations.DESCR FROM (((SQnet_TestValues INNER JOIN SQnet_TestDefinitions ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) INNER JOIN SQnet_Users ON SQnet_TestValues.USR_CODE = SQnet_Users.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN SQnet_Locations ON SQnet_TestDefinitions.PARENT_CODE = SQnet_Locations.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN SQnet_Measures ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_ID = SQnet_Measures.REC_CODE WHERE SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK >= getdate()-1 AND SQnet_TestValues.TESTDEVICE IN ('4','5') AND SQnet_Locations.DESCR like '%VW270%' AND SQnet_Locations.IDENTIFIER like '%A%'"
```

En la condición **getdate (-1)** me gusstaria añadir tambien una hora concreta. Es decir, que sea mayor o igual que ayer a las 06:00.

Saludos y gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución es utilizar las funciones DateDiff y DateAdd para poder sumar y restar unidades de tiempo a una fecha.

Por ejemplo:

```
Select DateAdd(dd,DateDiff(dd,0,GetDate()),-1);
```

[image: Dia Ayer]

Te devuelve el día de ayer. Por tanto solo tenemos que sumarle 6 horas.

```
DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME = DATEADD(hh,6,(DateAdd(dd,DateDiff(dd,0,GetDate()),-1)));
SELECT @FECHA;
```

[image: Resultado]

En tú código sería:

```
Select Distinct 
       sqnet_locations.descr
       From(((sqnet_testvalues
              Inner Join sqnet_testdefinitions On sqnet_testvalues.measure_dt = sqnet_testdefinitions.last_check)
              Inner Join sqnet_users On sqnet_testvalues.usr_code = sqnet_users.rec_code)
              Inner Join sqnet_locations On sqnet_testdefinitions.parent_code = sqnet_locations.rec_code)
              Inner Join sqnet_measures On sqnet_testvalues.measure_id = sqnet_measures.rec_code
       Where sqnet_testdefinitions.last_check >= DATEADD(hh,6,(DateAdd(dd,DateDiff(dd,0,GetDate()),-1)))
         And sqnet_testvalues.testdevice In('4', '5') 
         And sqnet_locations.descr Like '%VW270%'
         And sqnet_locations.identifier Like '%A%';
```

[Funciones de fecha útiles](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/15/funciones-de-fecha-para-datetime-utiles/)

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!